# Can't submit to App Store - Invalid Bundle

Tags: xcode4, app-store, appstore-approval

So I'm trying to submit my first app to the app store and I'm at the very last stage where I Archive the project and click "Distribute" to submit the binary.  However, when it goes to validate it, it pops up saying "This bundle is invalid.  The value of the CFBundleDocumentTypes key in the Info.plist must be an array of dictionaries, with each dictionary containing at least the CFBundleTypeName key."

Has anyone ever seen this before?  What could be causing it?

Answer (score 0):

Check your bundle identifier in the plist file as well as on your developer portal(provisioning profile). Both should be same. I think this could be a problem because I had faced this issue and ended up by knowing that there was some issue with the bundle id.

Hope it helps.